# Divide columns by a reference row

Tags: r, divide

I need to divide columns `despesatotal` and `despesamonetaria` by the row named Total:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: Well... I've tried: ```df <- df %>% mutate(percentage = despesatotal/[grup_CNAE=="Total"])```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your data set is `df`.

```
# 1) Delete the last row
     df <- df[-nrow(df),]
# 2) Build the desired data.frame [combining the CNAE names and the proportion columns
     new.df <- cbind(grup_CNAE = df$grup_CNAE,
                     100*prop.table(df[,-1],margin = 2))
```

Finally, rename your columns. Be careful with the `matrix` or `data.frame` formats, because sometimes mathematical operations may suppose a problem. If you you use `dput` function in order to give us a reproducible example, the answer would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get it done. This is not the best way, but I think it is very readable.

Suppose this is your data frame:

```
mydf = structure(list(grup_CNAE = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Total"
), despesatotal = c(71, 93, 81, 27, 39, 311), despesamonetaria = c(7, 
72, 36, 22, 73, 210)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

mydf

#  grup_CNAE despesatotal despesamonetaria
#1         A           71                7
#2         B           93               72
#3         C           81               36
#4         D           27               22
#5         E           39               73
#6     Total          311              210
```

To divide `despesatotal` values with its total value, you need to use the total value (`311` in this example) as the denominator. Note that the total value is located in the last row. You can identify its position by indexing the `despesatotal` column and use `nrow()` as the index value.

```
mydf |> mutate(percentage1 = despesatotal/despesatotal[nrow(mydf)], 
     percentage2 = despesamonetaria /despesamonetaria[nrow(mydf)])

#  grup_CNAE despesatotal despesamonetaria percentage1 percentage2
#1         A           71                7  0.22829582  0.03333333
#2         B           93               72  0.29903537  0.34285714
#3         C           81               36  0.26045016  0.17142857
#4         D           27               22  0.08681672  0.10476190
#5         E           39               73  0.12540193  0.34761905
#6     Total          311              210  1.00000000  1.00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Sample data

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   group despesatotal despesamonetaria
   <chr>        <int>            <int>
 1 1              198              586
 2 2              186              525
 3 3              202              563
 4 4              300              562
 5 5              126              545
 6 6              215              529
 7 7              183              524
 8 8              163              597
 9 9              213              592
10 10             175              530
11 Total         1961             5553

df %>% 
  mutate(percentage_total = despesatotal / last(despesatotal), 
         percentage_monetaria = despesamonetaria/ last(despesamonetaria)) %>%  
  slice(-nrow(.))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   group despesatotal despesamonetaria percentage_total percentage_monetaria
   <chr>        <int>            <int>            <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 1              198              586           0.101                0.106 
 2 2              186              525           0.0948               0.0945
 3 3              202              563           0.103                0.101 
 4 4              300              562           0.153                0.101 
 5 5              126              545           0.0643               0.0981
 6 6              215              529           0.110                0.0953
 7 7              183              524           0.0933               0.0944
 8 8              163              597           0.0831               0.108 
 9 9              213              592           0.109                0.107 
10 10             175              530           0.0892               0.0954
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use `dplyr::mutate(across())` to divide all relevant columns by the `Total` row. Note this is not sensitive to the order of the rows and will apply the manipulation to all numeric columns. You can supply any [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html) semantics to `across()` instead if needed in your case.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# make sample data
d <- tibble(grup_CNAE = paste0("Group", 1:12),
            despesatotal = sample(1e6:5e7, 12),
            despesamonetaria = sample(1e6:5e7, 12)) %>% 
  add_row(grup_CNAE = "Total", summarize(., across(where(is.numeric), sum)))

# divide numeric columns by value in "Total" row
d %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~./.[grup_CNAE == "Total"]))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#>    grup_CNAE despesatotal despesamonetaria
#>    <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 Group1          0.117            0.0204
#>  2 Group2          0.170            0.103 
#>  3 Group3          0.0451           0.0837
#>  4 Group4          0.0823           0.114 
#>  5 Group5          0.0170           0.0838
#>  6 Group6          0.0174           0.0612
#>  7 Group7          0.163            0.155 
#>  8 Group8          0.0352           0.0816
#>  9 Group9          0.0874           0.135 
#> 10 Group10         0.113            0.0877
#> 11 Group11         0.0499           0.0495
#> 12 Group12         0.104            0.0251
#> 13 Total           1                1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>