# Calculate percent from row total in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table:

| group | May 1990 | Jun 1990 | Jul 1990 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 581 | 552 | 465 |
| 2 | 193 | 184 | 176 |
| 3 | 207 | 177 | 165 |
| Total | 981 | 913 | 806 |

I want to calculate percent on row level from the row total.

| group | May 1990 | Jun 1990 | Jul 1990 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.59 | 0.60 | 0.58 |
| 2 | 0.19 | 0.21 | 0.22 |
| 3 | 0.21 | 0.19 | 0.20 |
| Total | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I got this far for now, but is not what I want.

```
df <- data.frame(group=c('1','2','3','Total'),may_1990=c(581,193,207,981),jun_1990=c(552,184,177,913),jul_1990=c(465,176,165,806))

total <- df %>% slice_tail(n = 1)
z <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x/total[-1]))
```

Comment: This has been already asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358188/divide-columns-by-a-reference-row

Comment: But I don't have fixed number of columns, I want to do it for all numeric columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `across`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x / .x[group == "Total"]))

  group  may_1990  jun_1990  jul_1990
1     1 0.5922528 0.6046002 0.5769231
2     2 0.1967380 0.2015334 0.2183623
3     3 0.2110092 0.1938664 0.2047146
4 Total 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

With the nature of your data, this could also work if you prefer base R:

```r
df[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], proportions) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to achieve this kind of table is to use table() function:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c('1','2','3','Total'),may_1990=c(581,193,207,981),jun_1990=c(552,184,177,913),jul_1990=c(465,176,165,806))

# Compute proportions for the central data
prop = proportions(as.matrix(df[-4,-1]), 2)

# Add total at the column level (margin = 1)
prop = addmargins(prop, 1)

# Create the final table
df_end = data.frame(
              group=c('1','2','3','Total'),
              prop
       
)
```

You obtain this:

```
    group  may_1990  jun_1990  jul_1990
1       1 0.5922528 0.6046002 0.5769231
2       2 0.1967380 0.2015334 0.2183623
3       3 0.2110092 0.1938664 0.2047146
Sum Total 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```